# python pool.map vs map

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, pool

I need to apply a complex function to a long series. Done sequentially this seems to be inefficient as I have access to a 12 core machine.

Before making significant investment in this, i wrote up this simple version which compares pool.map and map.

1) Surprisingly map is much much faster (see results below).

2) And there is an overflow error in the pool function which does not come up on the map version.

3) with a smaller array, the run time warning does not appear, but map is still faster.

I am not a computer science guy (just a functional user) - any thoughts and suggestions? I went with pool.map because the async version may mess up the order of the series (which is a pain for me to sort out).

SEE UPDATE BELOW : Based on Jdog's suggestion.

Config: python v 2.7, 64 bit version, windows 7

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        poolMap
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time

def func(x):
   y=x*x
   return y

def worker(inputs):
   num=mp.cpu_count()
   print 'num of cpus', num
   pool = mp.Pool(num)
   #inputs = list(inputs)
   #print "inputs type",type(inputs)
   results = pool.map(func, inputs)
   pool.close()
   pool.join()
   return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
   series = np.arange(500000)
   start = time.clock()
   poolAnswer = worker(series)
   end = time.clock()
   print 'pool time' ,(end - start)
   start = time.clock()
   answer = map(func,series)
   end = time.clock()
   print 'map time', (end - start)
```

results:

num of cpus 12

pool time 2.40276007188

D:\poolmap.py:19: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
      y=x*x

map time 0.904187849745

##############UPDATE

Using this func gave me the results I was looking for

```
def func(x):
    x=float(x)
    y=(((x*x)**0.35))*x+np.ma.sqrt((((x*x)**0.35)))
    return y
```

results:
num of cpus 12

pool time 12.7410957475

map time 45.4550067581

Comment: Also no computer scientist, but perhaps such a short time interval is playing out of `pool.map`'s hands as it has to set up everything. Make `func` a bit more intensive and try again.

Comment: I didnt make the function more complex, just increased the arange to 20 million, results are even more sad : num of cpus 12
pool time 84.3208359572
map time 6.6808615689
numexpr time 0.0632046093354

Comment: Jdog - thanks - throwing in an uglier function changed the performance dramatically. Interestingly just using numpy arrays to compute series*series is the super fastest. It looks like some serious optimization has gone into the more basic array operations. multiply(series,series) was way faster than the original pool or map functions. I wonder why though!

Comment: `multiprocessing.pool` adds significant overhead because of processes being started and data being sent between them. It's mostly useful when you do heavy computations, not trivial ones like squaring. As for NumPy, it's fast because it doesn't have to do all the typechecking that Python does.

Comment: Btw., NumPy built with the right options can do multithreading internally, so there's how you can leverage your multicore processor. E.g., have a look at [Enthought Python](http://enthought.com/products/epd.php).